# Apache poi loses shape quality when rendering to BufferedImage

Tags: java, apache-poi, rendering, bufferedimage

I have a slideshow with some simple shapes in PowerPoint. I am loading it with Apache Poi:

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = MY_SLIDE_SHOW;

for (XSLFSlide slide: ppt.getSlides()) {

     List<XSLFShape> shapeList = slide.getShapes();

     for (XSLFShape shape: shapeList) {

         // data about shape dimensions
         Rectangle2D anchor = shape.getAnchor();

         // buffered image to draw into
         BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)anchor.getWidth(), (int)anchor.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
         Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();

         // set a clear transparent background to the image
         graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
         graphics.fillRect(0, 0, (int)anchor.getWidth(), (int)anchor.getHeight());

         // draw the shape into the buffered image
         graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
         shape.draw(graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)anchor.getWidth(), (int)anchor.getHeight()));
         graphics.dispose();
     }
}
```

However, while I am able to render the shapes they come out at a much lower resolution and lose any effects (glow, bevel, 3d format, shadow, reflection, etc.)

Here below is a comparison of the powerpoint (with effects) and the rendered object (without effects):

[image: Comparison]

I believe the required solution will likely be threefold and so would appreciate answers to:

- How to render the shape effects along with the shapes?
- How to render the shapes at a higher resolution than face value and then scale down (rather than at a lower resolution and scaling up as it seems to currently be doing)?
- How to render the shapes with transparent backgrounds, which I am surprised is not currently working?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm taking care of the POI slideshow rendering. w.r.t. your questions: a) shape effects aren't implemented yet. b) idk what you mean, you can [specify a scaling factor](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html), c) there are cases, where the background is opaque. If you want that partly to be solved, please open a [bugzilla ticket](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI&component=SL+Common&short_desc=slideshow+rendering+issue&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All) and attach your file.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Much appreciated! w.r.t -> a) okay, b) I will see if that addresses the quality of my shapes. c) will do.